# What is the difference between the verticall offset of a ScrollViewer itself and that of ScrollChangedEventArgs

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, onscrollchanged

I set a ScrollChangedEventHandler for a ScrollViewer as shown in the code below.

```
private void scrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
    if (scrollViewer == null) 
        return; 

    Console.WriteLine(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset); 
    Console.WriteLine(e.VerticalOffset);
}
```

Sometimes, the 2 VerticalOffsets result in different values.
Could you tell me what is the actual difference between the verticall offset of a ScrollViewer itself and that of ScrollChangedEventArgs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a conclusion from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollchangedeventargs.verticaloffset) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticaloffset) for those two properties :

**ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset**: represent the original value of the ScrollViewer Vertical offset 
 (before you do the scroll, means the vertical offset **before** the event is triggered)

**e.VerticalOffset**: represents the new updated value of the Vertical offset of the ScrollViewer 
 (after you do the scroll, means the value of the vertical offset **after** the event is triggered)

For general-purpose, you will use the `e.VerticalOffset` property.

---

NOTE: the same is applied to the `HorizontalOffset` property.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer.